Cannot stop MySQL slave replication for some db using binlog-ignore-db and replicate-ignore-db
I want to stop replicating system database like mysql using binlog-ignore-db and replicate-ignore-db, the settings are applied:
master:
mysql> SHOW BINARY LOG STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: binlog.000001
         Position: 1251
     Binlog_Do_DB: 
 Binlog_Ignore_DB: mysql
Executed_Gtid_Set: 990ca1d0-beab-11ef-aa36-ba9eeabae344:1-4
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

slave:
mysql> SHOW REPLICA STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Replica_IO_State: Waiting for source to send event
                  Source_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Source_User: replica
                  Source_Port: 3301
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Source_Log_File: binlog.000001
          Read_Source_Log_Pos: 1251
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 1462
        Relay_Source_Log_File: binlog.000001
           Replica_IO_Running: Yes
          Replica_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: mysql
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Source_Log_Pos: 1251
              Relay_Log_Space: 1679
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Source_SSL_Allowed: No
           Source_SSL_CA_File: 
           Source_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Source_SSL_Cert: 
            Source_SSL_Cipher: 
               Source_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Source: 0
Source_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Source_Server_Id: 1
                  Source_UUID: 990ca1d0-beab-11ef-aa36-ba9eeabae344
             Source_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
    Replica_SQL_Running_State: Replica has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Source_Retry_Count: 10
                  Source_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Source_SSL_Crl: 
           Source_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 990ca1d0-beab-11ef-aa36-ba9eeabae344:1-4
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 990ca1d0-beab-11ef-aa36-ba9eeabae344:1-4,
99293d0e-beab-11ef-9b97-00b58ea694f2:1
                Auto_Position: 1
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Source_TLS_Version: 
       Source_public_key_path: 
        Get_Source_public_key: 1
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Meanwhile, replicate-wild-ignore-table=mysql.% works, why?

Since the configurations seems correct on not replicating mysql system schema ,  how do you/we know that the data is still replicating ? Personally , I choose that master dumps all logs, on the slave part I choose which one I should replicate by using Replicate_Do_DB settings.

@ErgestBasha Because after the slave started replicating, the slave user will also be added in slave node.
